# Scheme Recursion and Updated Condition

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm having trouble incorporating a recursive function that squares a number. 
Basically I am trying to write a function that keeps calling the Add function x number of times to square it. So if it is 7 it should call it seven times to get 49.

```
(define (Add a b)
  (if (and (number? a) (number? b))
      (+ a b)
      (lambda (x)
        (+ (a x) (b x)))))

(define i 0)
(define ans 0)

(define (Square a)
  (when (> i a)
     ((Add a ans) (+ i 1 ))))
```

The main issue I'm running into is that the square function only goes through the loop once, I'm not sure why the condition won't update/keep going through the loop till it reaches that condition.

Comment: `when` isn't a looping form but a one way `if`. You do looping with recursion in Scheme.

Comment: Okay and how would I go about doing such? I've tried looking around online but I'm really confused on how to implement it.

Comment: Something like this: `(define (test n) (define (aux c acc) (if (< c 0) acc (aux (- c 1) (if (odd? c) (cons c acc) acc)))) (aux n '())) (test 5) ;==> (1 3 5)`

Comment: Okay so I tried utilizing your test case but I am still having trouble incorporating it into my function: '(define (square n)
  (when (negative? n)
    (* n -1))
  (if (< i n)
      ((Add ans n) (+ i 1) (square n))))'

Comment: If you look at my procedure (not test case) it makes a helper with the values that change in the loop and I'm using it to do the looping. Have another look at that. `when` is just for side effects and in your example it does nothing since `(* n -1)` does not change `n`. `Add` is very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Writing `square` directly is a big pain. It's much easier to write a recursive `multiply` function and then just have your square function call `multiply`. Follow the design recipe for recursion on the natural numbers, as it appears in section [9.3 of HtDP](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html#%28part._sec~3anats%29).

By the way, if you haven't already written a bunch of recursive functions on more standard self-referential data definitions (e.g. lists), then, well, I claim that your instructor is doing in wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should make everything that **changes** parameters. Imagine you want to make the `factorial` then two values change. It's the result and the iteration of the number down to zero.

```
(define (factorial value)
  (define (helper cur ans)
    (if (zero? cur)
        ans                    ; finished. return the answer
        (helper (- cur 1)      ; recur by updating n
                (* cur ans)))) ; and update the answer

  (helper value 1))
```

Again. It's **exactly** the same as my example in the comment except it does something else at each step. The basic building blocks are the same and something that would square the argument is very similar.